# Ionic - Exibir side menu em todas as view, exceto na pagina principal

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Oi. Estou com um problema em relação ao side menu do Ionic. Preciso exibir ele em todas as views, exceto na primeira.

Eu tentei colocar todas as views com o side menu, e dar hide no botão do menu na pagina principal, mas ao colocar hide no botão, ele desaparece em todas as views. Então isso não deu certo.

Depois eu também tentei inserir o side menu em todas as views, exceto na pagina principal, porem como o side menu está sendo criado na "pagina 2", não aparece o back-button para levar de volta a pagina principal. Ao inspecionar o elemento, percebi que o back-button existe, porem com uma classe hide que não consigo alterar. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Preciso ver como está chamando o icone do menu. No meu app eu coloco os botões dentro de um "<ion-nav-buttons side="left">" apenas nas páginas que quero o botão do menu.

Answer (score 1):

Essa documentação pode te ajudar: [Ionic History](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/)

Use o `$ionicHistory.currentView()` para ver se esta na pagina principal, se estiver esconda o side-menu: [Side-menu](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/)

Answer (score 1):

Na prática basta você criar uma rota para o menu e utilizar nas páginas que desejar, por exemplo :

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('testModule').config(router);
    router.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

    function router($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('menu', {
                url: '/menu',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'menu/menu.html',
                controller: 'menuController'
            }).state('menu.pageOne', {
                url: '/pageOne',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'pageOne/pageOne.html',
                        controller: 'pageOneController'
                    }
                }
            }).state('menu.pageTwo', {
                url: '/pageTwo',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'pageTwo/pageTwo.html',
                        controller: 'pageTwoController'
                    }
                }
            }).state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    }
})();
```

Nessa situação, por exemplo a pagina de login não está com o menu. Sendo assim todas as vezes que for redirecionar para tela de login o menu não aparecerá.

Comment: olá estou com um problema parecido e sou novo com ionic,
meu código esta parecido com o seu, no entanto, não entendi de onde vem esse menuContent e também, se eu informar  menu.Page já inclui a view menu?

Answer (score 1):

Em sua view, utilize `hide-nav-bar="true"` como no exemplo a seguir:

```
<ion-view title="Sua localização" hide-nav-bar="true">

    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header" has-bouncing="true">
```

Em relação ao back button, antes de chamar outra tela utilize:

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                disableBack: false,
                historyRoot: true
            });

            $ionicHistory.clearCache();
            $ionicHistory.clearHistory();

$state.go("a_sua_view_no_apps");
```